# (c = getchar()) != EOF in C#?

Tags: c#, c

What is the C# equivalent of the following C code:

```
while((c = getchar())!= EOF)
   putchar(c);
```

I know getchar() and putchar() are going to be replaced by Console.Read and Console.Write respectively but what about the EOF. Especially keeping in mind, C# works with unicode and C with ASCII, what are the implications of that ??

Comment: Did you check the documentation for Console.Read? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read.aspx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Console.Read()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read.aspx) returns -1 on EOF (coincidentally, [EOF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file) is defined as `-1` on most platforms).

You can do:

```
int c;
while ((c = Console.Read()) != -1) {
   Console.Write(Convert.ToChar(c));
}
```

Also, C# works natively with `UNICODE` in the same way that C works natively with `ASCII`, i.e. there are no more implications. [System.Char](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.aspx) represents an [UCS-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16/UCS-2) `UNICODE` character, which also fits into an `int`, so everything will be all right.

Answer (score 3):

Off the top of my head,

```
int c; // N.B. not char
while((c = Console.In.Read()) != -1)
    Console.Out.Write((char)c);
```

Apparently [Read()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w3csw16.aspx) returns -1 if there's nothing more to read. I don't see an EOF constant defined. I might be inclined to use `>= 0` instead of `!= -1` even.

I don't think ANSI vs Unicode makes any difference - you're reading a number from one API call and feeding it into the other. You can use Unicode in C too.

Comment: Do you know what will happen if you call `Console.Out.Write(int)` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
        int c = -1;
        while ( (c =Console.Read()) >=0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(c);
        }
```

Comment: So there is no real equivalent of C's EOF in C# ??

Comment: What's with the call to WriteLine? And why are you writing numbers?

Comment: @Fahad: The real equivalent is the constant value -1. This is the documented return value when you don't have more to read.